# Do not repeat yourself best practices showing and hiding fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I am trying to figure out the best way to show and hide fields that are being reused. Cleaning up the code so that I do not repeat myself "DRY". Will someone please assist me in the best practices of doing so?

What I have is a select that allows the user to choose from two different reports.

```
<select class="form-control" id="reporttype" name="reporttype"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Report</option>
    <option id ="checklistreport" value="checklistreport" >Checklist Stats</option>
    <option id ="locationreport" value="locationreport" >Location Stats</option>
</select>
```

Then each report have a lot of similar fields. How can I have them use the same fields but hide/show the differences and go to the correct form "action" based which report is chosen.

**Location Report**

```
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_location_queries.cfm">

<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" required size="9">
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
    <option value="FSC">FSC</option>
</select>

<button id="add" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

<textarea id="selected" rows="10" readonly></textarea>

<br /><br />

<label for="StartDate">From</label>
<input type='text' name="StartDate" id="StartDate" value="" required/>

<br /><br />

<label for="EndDate">To</label>
<input type='text' name="EndDate" id="EndDate" value="" required/>

<br /><br />

<label for="Format">Format</label>
<select name="Format" required>
    <option selected value="">Select Format</option>
    <option value="print">Print</option>
    <option value="pdf">Preview</option>
    <option value="xls">Excel</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />

</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = true;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = false;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('loc').addEventListener('change', reflectChange);

function reflectChange() {
    document.getElementById('selected').value = '';

    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        if(opts[i].selected)
        document.getElementById('selected').value += opts[i].text+'\n';
    }
}
</script>
```

**Checklist Report**

```
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_checklists_queries.cfm">

<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" required size="8">
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
    <option value="FSC">FSC</option>
</select>

<button id="add" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

<textarea id="selected" rows="7" readonly></textarea>

<br /><br />

        <cfquery name="GetActiveEmps" datasource="tco_associates">
           SELECT assoc_userid, assoc_last, assoc_first FROM tco_associates
           WHERE assoc_status = 'ACTIVE' 
           and assoc_last NOT LIKE 'Test%' 
           and len(assoc_last) > 0 
           ORDER BY assoc_last
        </cfquery>    

<select name="EmployeeName" id="EmployeeName" multiple="multiple" required size="8">
  <cfoutput query="GetActiveEmps">
      <option value="#assoc_userid#">#Trim(assoc_last)#, #Trim(assoc_first)#</option>
  </cfoutput>
</select>

<button id="add1" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem1" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

<textarea id="selected1" rows="7" readonly></textarea>

<br /><br />

<label for="StartDate">From</label>
<input type='text' name="StartDate" id="StartDate" value="" required/>

<br /><br />

<label for="EndDate">To</label>
<input type='text' name="EndDate" id="EndDate" value="" required/>

<br /><br />

<label for="Format">Format</label>
<select name="Format" required>
    <option selected value="">Select Format</option>
    <option value="print">Print</option>
    <option value="pdf">Preview</option>
    <option value="xls">Excel</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
// JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = true;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = false;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('loc').addEventListener('change', reflectChange);

function reflectChange() {
    document.getElementById('selected').value = '';

    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        if(opts[i].selected)
        document.getElementById('selected').value += opts[i].text+'\n';
    }
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

// JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
var opts1 = document.querySelectorAll('#EmployeeName option');

document.getElementById('add1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        opts1[i].selected = true;
    }

    reflectChange1();
});

document.getElementById('rem1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        opts1[i].selected = false;
    }

    reflectChange1();
});

document.getElementById('EmployeeName').addEventListener('change', reflectChange1);

function reflectChange1() {
    document.getElementById('selected1').value = '';

    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        if(opts1[i].selected)
        document.getElementById('selected1').value += opts1[i].text+'\n';
    }
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
   </script>
```

Many of these fields are the same is there a way i can just have one set and show them if either option is chosen and not have two different sets?

**This is what I have tried:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="reporttype" name="reporttype"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Report</option>
    <option id ="checklistreports" value="checklistreports" >Checklist Stats</option>
    <option id ="locationreports" value="locationreports" >Location Stats</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#reporttype', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        //var checklistreport = $("#checklistreport");
        //var locationreport = $("#locationreport");
        var location = $("#location");
        var employeelist = $("#employeelist");
        var chosendates = $("#chosendates");
        var formattype = $("#formattype");
        var submitbtn = $("#submitbtn");

        if (value == "checklistreports") {
            //checklistreport.show();
            //locationreport.hide();
            location.show();
            employeelist.show();
            chosendates.show();
            formattype.show();
            submitbtn.show();
        } else if (value == "locationreports") {
            //checklistreport.hide();
            //locationreport.show();
            location.show();
            employeelist.hide();
            chosendates.show();
            formattype.show();
            submitbtn.show();
        } else {
            //checklistreport.hide();
            //locationreport.hide();
            location.hide();
            employeelist.hide();
            chosendates.hide();
            formattype.hide();
            submitbtn.hide();
        }
    });
</script>
<br /><br />

<!--<div id="locationreport" style="display: none;">-->
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_location_queries.cfm">
<!--<div id="checklistreport" style="display: none;">-->
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_checklists_queries.cfm">




</form>

<div id="location" style="display: none;">
<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" required size="9">
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
    <option value="FSC">FSC</option>
</select>

<button id="add" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

<textarea id="selected" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
<br /><br />

<div id="employeelist" style="display: none;">
        <cfquery name="GetActiveEmps" datasource="tco_associates">
           SELECT assoc_userid, assoc_last, assoc_first FROM tco_associates
           WHERE assoc_status = 'ACTIVE' 
           and assoc_last NOT LIKE 'Test%' 
           and len(assoc_last) > 0 
           ORDER BY assoc_last
        </cfquery>    

<select name="EmployeeName" id="EmployeeName" multiple="multiple" required size="9">
  <cfoutput query="GetActiveEmps">
      <option value="#assoc_userid#">#Trim(assoc_last)#, #Trim(assoc_first)#</option>
  </cfoutput>
</select>

<button id="add1" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem1" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

<textarea id="selected1" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
<br /><br />

<div id="chosendates" style="display: none;">
<label for="StartDate">From</label>
<input type='text' name="StartDate" id="StartDate" value="" required/>

<br /><br />

<label for="EndDate">To</label>
<input type='text' name="EndDate" id="EndDate" value="" required/>
    </div>
<br /><br />

<div id="formattype" style="display: none;">
<label for="Format">Format</label>
<select name="Format" required>
    <option selected value="">Select Format</option>
    <option value="print">Print</option>
    <option value="pdf">Preview</option>
    <option value="xls">Excel</option>
</select>
    </div>
<br /><br />

<div id="submitbtn" style="display: none;">
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />
    </div>
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = true;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = false;
    }

    reflectChange();
});

document.getElementById('loc').addEventListener('change', reflectChange);

function reflectChange() {
    document.getElementById('selected').value = '';

    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        if(opts[i].selected)
        document.getElementById('selected').value += opts[i].text+'\n';
    }
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

// JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
var opts1 = document.querySelectorAll('#EmployeeName option');

document.getElementById('add1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        opts1[i].selected = true;
    }

    reflectChange1();
});

document.getElementById('rem1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        opts1[i].selected = false;
    }

    reflectChange1();
});

document.getElementById('EmployeeName').addEventListener('change', reflectChange1);

function reflectChange1() {
    document.getElementById('selected1').value = '';

    for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
        if(opts1[i].selected)
        document.getElementById('selected1').value += opts1[i].text+'\n';
    }
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
   </script>
```

Not sure how I choose which action for the form. Depending on which report is chosen.

https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/o2gxgz9r/10018/

Comment: You could put common selects/options in separate `.cfm` files and include them. Another option would be using [`<cfmodule>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmodule.html), provide the form type as attribute and switch the corresponding fields within the module.

Comment: Is it possible to make like components maybe using JavaScript or so?

Comment: If you want/can do it on clientside, have a look at [HTML5 <template>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

**Option #1:**

Always show the "common" inputs, and only hide the inputs that are conditional upon selection, that way your code is cleaner because you only have to manage the conditional elements (not all of them as you are doing now)

**Option #2:**

Use CF includes to hold your "common" elements, and "conditional" elements, combining them where necessary to build the correct list.

**Option #3:**

Use JavaScript to hold your "common" elements, and "conditional" elements, and render the composed list based on your conditions.

```
var location = $('select[name=Location]');

// This lists could hold anything you want, jQuery elements
// references, strings, etc.
var lists = {
    common: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    locationreports: ['location #1', 'location #2'],
    checklistreports: ['checklist  #1', 'checklist #2']
};

$('#reporttype').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  // Grab a copy of the common list to begin with
  var options = [].concat(lists.common);

  // Now combine the conditional options
  if (value === "checklistreports" || value === "locationreports") {
    options = options.concat(lists[value]);
  }

  // Now you have a complete list of options to show based
  // your conditions, so now you can just show them all, or
  // do whatever you want with this new list.

  location.empty();

  options.forEach(function($element) {
    // Do something with the list
    location.append('<option value="' + $element + '">' + $element + '</option>');
  })
```

There are lots of other options, but between using and combining includes, or composing objects together you should be able to customize a nice DRY workflow.